# How to perform interpolation on 2d grid from dataframe in python?

Tags: python, interpolation

I would like to know how to interpolate values on a 2d grid using dataframe data.

My data is below

```
        500   1000  1400  1600  
   0    78.0  86.4  89.1  90.0  
   10   78.8  87.0  89.6  90.5  
   20   79.6  87.5  90.0  90.9
```

how to get [ X=15 , Y=750 ]  ?

Comment: I changed your title from 3d interpolation to 2d interpolation, as you have data on a 2d grid.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either [`scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator.html#scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator) or [`scipy.interpolate.interpn`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interpn.html#scipy.interpolate.interpn):

You are talking about a dataframe, so I am putting your data into a pandas dataframe first:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.interpolate import interpn, RegularGridInterpolator

values = np.array([
    [78.0,  86.4,  89.1,  90.0],
    [78.8,  87.0,  89.6,  90.5],
    [79.6,  87.5,  90.0,  90.9]
])

df = pd.DataFrame(
    values, index=[0, 10, 20], columns=[500, 1000, 1400, 1600]
)
print(df)
#        500    1000    1400    1600
# 0     78.0    86.4    89.1    90.0
# 10    78.8    87.0    89.6    90.5
# 20    79.6    87.5    90.0    90.9
```

Now, run the interpolation:

```
point = (15, 750)

# Method 1 (RegularGridInterpolator)
interp = RegularGridInterpolator(
    (df.index, df.columns), df.values, method='linear'
)
print(interp(point))
# 83.225

# Method 2 (interpn)
print(interpn([df.index, df.columns], df.values, point, method='linear'))
# [83.225]
```

Comment: Thanks so much !^^ it was greatful !!

Comment: @wonsiklee You are welcome. If my answer helped you, consider accepting the answer - you can do this by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.